# 4 months developmental leap

Tags: sleep, sleep-training, nightwaking, naps

We have a 4 month old daughter who has been a good night sleeper before, goes to sleep around 8-9pm and sleeps 4-5h, eats (bottle) and sleeps another 3-4h and eats, then sleeps more 3h. Sometimes even full night with no feeding, and sometimes with one feed.

She naps about 5h a day currently, 3-4 naps. She sleeps only 1st cycle but we lengthen some of the naps by holding her. She can do about 1.5h awake, otherwise becomes very cranky and hard to get to sleep. But she seems quite tired during the day..

She generally falls asleep with pacifier and us holding her to sleep. Then I move her to her crib. Sometimes when I move her to her crib she wakes up a bit to notice she is in her crib but continues sleeping.

We have a bedtime routine, diaper change, pyjamas, book and a song.

She has entered into this developmental leap about 2 weeks ago I guess, she only wants to eat in a darker room and fights all naps.

Two last nights she has been waking up every 1h! She talks alone for some minutes and then cries. Sometimes helps I give the pacifier back, sometimes I need to hold her (most of the time). My question is, Does this mean she has already developed a sleep association for us holding her to sleep and now I need to stop doing that? Or is this just normal phase of the leap and will get better after? Back to normal? Because we always held her to sleep and yet still she slept the nights better.

And please, any tips on how to stop holding her to sleep if she always fights to sleep?

Thanks!